# Returns enum value as T in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to implement a generic method with a generic Type `T` that takes a `Type enumType` as parameter  and returns a `IDictionary<T, string>`.

Basically, I want to return a dictionary that pairs all the values of a enum with a custom label. For instance, supposing I have these enums:

```
public enum SOEnum
{
    FirstVal,
    SecondVal,
    ThirdVal,
}

public enum FooEnum
{
    Abc = 1,
    Def = 2,
    Ghi = 4
}

public enum BarEnum
{
    Pippo = 'Pippo',
    Pluto = 'Pluto'
}
```

Depending on the parameter passed, I'd like to obtain a dictionary like this:

```
// In case the input is SOEnum.GetType() //
var dictionary = new Dictionary<SOEnum, string>()
{
    { SOEnum.FirstVal, "This is the first Value" },
    { SoEnum.SecondVal, "What a wonderful new" },
    { SOEnum.ThirdVal, "That's ok" }
}

// In case the input is FooEnum.GetType() //
var dictionary = new Dictionary<FooEnum, string>()
{
    { FooEnum.Abc, "Label 1" },
    { FooEnum.Def, "Label 2" },
    { FooEnum.Ghi, "Label 3" }
}

// In case the input is BarEnum.GetType() //
var dictionary = new Dictionary<BarEnum, string>()
{
    { BarEnum.Pippo, "Label of Pippo" },
    { BarEnum.Pluto, "Label of Pluto" },
}
```

Note that I **DON'T** want to put the labels in the enum, because the enum could already have the int association.

Anyways, I thought at something like this:

```
public override IDictionary<T, string> GetEnumLabels<T>(Type enumType)
{
    if (!typeof(T).IsEnum || !enumType.IsEnum)
        throw new ArgumentException("T must be an enumerated type");
    if (enumType == typeof(SOEnum) && typeof(T) == typeof(SOEnum))
    {
        return new Dictionary<T, string>()
        {
            {(T)SOEnum.FirstVal, "This is the first Value" },
            {(T)SOEnum.SecondVal, "What a wonderful new" },
            {(T)SOEnum.ThirdVal, "That's ok"}
        };
   }

   else if (enumType == typeof(FooEnum) && typeof(T) == typeof(FooEnum))
   {
        return new Dictionary<T, string>()
        {
            { (T)FooEnum.Abc, "Label 1" },
            { (T)FooEnum.Def, "Label 2" },
            { (T)FooEnum.Ghi, "Label 3" }
        };
   }

    else if (enumType == typeof(BarEnum) && typeof(T) == typeof(BarEnum))
   {
        return new Dictionary<T, string>()
        {
            { (T)BarEnum.Pippo, "Label of Pippo" },
            { (T)BarEnum.Pluto, "Label of Pluto" },
        };
   }


   return null;
}
```

But the problem is that I cannot convert from any enum to `T` like that

Comment: Why make the SOEnum T, if the dictionary "slot" you save it in is T then it shouldn't matter what type SOEnum is shouldn't it`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. If you mean if I can avoid casting to `T`, then I got the error 'Argument1: cannot convert from `SOEnum` to `T`'.

Comment: Why have a generic method in the first place if the only enum it's able to process is `SOEnum`? I also have no idea what you mean by *because the enum could already have the int association*.

Comment: Have a look into this: https://www.codementor.io/@cerkit/giving-an-enum-a-string-value-using-the-description-attribute-6b4fwdle0 Would that be a viable alternative?

Comment: so why are you not using something like `[Display(Name = "This is the first Value")]` on top of `FirstVal = 1`?

Comment: @GSerg i'm sorry, probably it wasn't clear from the example: inside `GetEnumLabels` I would have multiple `if-else`, catching all the possibile enums. Assume you also have a second enum `FooEnum`, then I should retrieve also its label using `GetEnumLabels`.
And with 'because the enum could already have the int association' I meant that the enum could already be something like enum foo { First = 1, Second = 2, Third = 4 }.
@Fildor and @Hoshani that could actually be useful. I can try this approach, just I'm afraid I might not be able to decorate all the enums

Comment: This is a misuse/abuse of generics. You should write a separate method for each enum, rather than having a big if-else chain.

Comment: So you have the master enum `SOEnum` that contains the values and their descriptions. Then you have a bunch of other enums *some* values in which are numerically equal to those of the master enum. For each of these other enums, you want a mapping of only those of their values that happen to match the master enum values, which also implicitly gives you the descriptions from the master enum? What are you going to do with the values from the other enums that do not equal to anything from the master enum?

Comment: @GSerg: Uhm not quite like that. I'm sorry, I have updated the examples so that you can understand better what is the problem. Sweeper: honestly, with Hoshani hint I can achieve what I need, but now I'd like to know if something like this is possible or not

Comment: Your edit made it worse. Now it looks like each enum has its own descriptions, at which point it's not clear what is the significance of `SOEnum` in all this.

Comment: `SOEnum` is just an enum, like `FooEnum` and `BarEnum`. At first I wrote only `SOEnum` because I thought it would have been clear enough, but I was wrong. These enum are all equally important

Comment: ... is what you want just `var d = ((SOEnum[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SOEnum))).Select(x => new { v = x, d = GetDisplayName(x) }).ToDictionary(x => x.v, x => x.d);`?

Comment: this is not allowed in enums of C# `Pluto = 'Pluto'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use generic method since it is only limited to enums.

you should put attributes on every enum like this

```cs
public enum FooEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "This is the first Value")]
    OneVal,
}

public enum BarEnum
{
    [Display(Name = "This is X Value")]
    XVal,
}
```

and then whenever you want to get the display value

```cs
public static string GetDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
{
    var attr = enumValue.GetType()
        .GetMember(enumValue.ToString())
        .First()
        .GetCustomAttribute<DisplayAttribute>();
    if (attr == null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("enum has no display attribute");
    }

    return attr.Name;
}
```